# How to manage a list elements staying on the same page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

By default, rails has controller CRUD actions with corresponding routes. For instance, I have a simple bookstore app, where I have a book and category. I want to display all categories through a sidebar on a home page. Each category is a dropdown element accompanied with a books count integer. When expanding a dropdown I want to see a book title that belongs to a current and acts as link. That is easy to implement.

**The question is how can I add a form hidden under, let's say a + sign, sticked next to a static Dropdown section title "Categories" if there are none?**

A form for Create action in Category controller which would allow to create a new category and display it straight away without redirecting to Create category view and redirecting back.

Please advise any reliable solution or tutorial link. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for an AJAX form. In rails you can generate this with form_for ... remote:true. This can call a controller method with out refreshing the page. You can then return a response and use JS to update the page the user is on.

For example, in your view

```
<div class="hidden">
  <%= from_for @category, remote:true %>
  Your form here
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Add in some JavaScript to un-hide the form when your button is clicked. In your controller

```
def create
#normal create stuff
  if save
    respond_to do |f|
      f.js
      f.html {#re render page just in case JavaScript is disabled}
    end
  else
    #handle error
  end
end
```

using the rails default f.js, Rails will call a file create.js.erb this file will have access to any public variable you make, for instance @category.

you can then do somthing along the lines of

```
$('.append_category').append('<%= j render 'your category layout partial', locals: { category: @category }%>');
```

or if you just need the category link

```
$('.append_category').append('<%= link_to @category %>');
```

A very nice guide can be found here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Note: depending on your version of rails, you may need to add include ActionController::MimeResponds to your application_controller.rb (I know this is required in rails 5)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to use it